# Hyperplane defined by n points

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra

I've the following problem:

Given n points in a space, I'm searching a hyperplane that goes through them.

The easiest example of such a problem is two points (x_1=0,x_2=0) and (1,-1) and I would like to get 1*x_1+1*x_2=0 returned.

My points will be n-tuples of 32-bit integers. The coefficients a_i of the desired hyperplane a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + ... = c must be 32-bit integers as well. In case the hyperplane cannot be defined this way, I would like to have this reported.

My project is coded in c++.

I would probably able to code this up by myself but I anticipate that this would be quite a bit of work. Also, my hunch is that this is a problem general enough that there might be an open-source library which would solve my problem. Does anybody know about a library which could solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is not very hard, given that the given points are linear independent.

Let u^i in Z^n be your nodes, then define v^i as (u^i_0, ..., u^i_{n-1},-1).

Now create a matrix A

```
( v^0_0     v^0_1 ...     v^0_n     )
( v^1_0     v^1_1 ...     v^1_n     )
    .         .             .
    .         .             .
    .         .             .
( v^{n-2}_0 v^{n-2}_1 ... v^{n-2}_n )
```

What you have to solve is A * x == 0.

Now go ahead and perform the Gaussian elimination. Make sure that you still let the coefficients to be integers. So instead of doing r_k -= r_ki * r_i / r_ii, you'll have to do r_k = r_ki * r_i - r_ii * r_k. After each step, divide the processed row by its greatest common divisor. This usually avoids overflow. If you experience overflows, just use a larger type for the matrix operations itself.

In the end, you'll have a matrix in which there are at most two columns that have more than one entry. Your solution will depend on the choice of values of these two rows only, e.g. it will look something like

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
2 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 1
```

assign any values to x_0 and x_1 (in this example) and you're done.
The last value of x will be your right hand side of the hyperplane equality.

Comment: It's a lot harder than you make it sound, since doing what you suggest will quickly lead to overflow.

Comment: @Antimony the OPs problem states clearly that all values must be integers, so no additional library needed.

Comment: @Antimony I actually have done this myself in the last week and: No, it doesn't usually generate overflows if you just divide all rows by its greatest common divisor frequently

Comment: All the values are intgers, but the intermediate calculations involve fractions, some of which can get quite large. Unless you feel like implementing rational arithmetic yourself, you need a library.

Comment: @Antimony Read my algorithm again, I clearly said how to avoid fractions.

Comment: Yes, at the expense of having overflow instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14220/discussion-between-antimony-and-stefan)

Comment: @Antimony Just as I said: use gcd. If it still occurs, just use a bigger type of ints for the matrix operations. It's simple.

Comment: And what happens once 'a bigger type' requires more than 64 bits? You need an arbitrary precision library.

Comment: I eventually decided to go with this suggestion. I've been quite reluctant to implement Gaussian elimination by myself because I felt that there should be some package for this, but I've not been successful in finding anything useful (see comment below regarding linbox). I did not use int32_t or int64_t because in both cases, the risk of overflows is real as I've numbers in the full spectrum of int32_t. Instead, I used Gnu MPZ. So far, this works well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself, but [LinBox](http://www.linalg.org/overview.html) looks like what you want.

Comment: Initially, I felt the idea to use LinBox would be best. However, in the current form, I think that the package is rather user unfriendly. I spent more than one full day trying to get something small running, and I've not been successful. Eventually, I gave up. Here are the problems: (1) The packaged version in Ubuntu doesn't work out of the box (missing dependencies when compiling an example). (2) Downloading the source from scratch requires downloading a myriad of packages. After downloading, it is a puzzle to figure out which ones are actually compatible. (3) The tutorials are outdated.

Comment: @Holger, sorry about that. Like I said, I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is solving a system of linear equations:

```
X*A = C
```

where A = (a_1, ..., a_n)^T,  C= (c, ..., c)^T. They are both `n` by 1 vectors. And `X` is a `m` by `n` matrix

```
x^1_1  ...  x^1_n
x^2_1  ...  x^2_n
  .     .     .
  .     .     .
  .     .     .
x^m_1  ...  x^m_n
```

where each row is the coordinate of a point. Suppose there are `m` points (no matter they are linear dependent or not), and `m<=n`.

To solve the linear equations, try 2 cases: C = (1, ..., 1)^T, and C = (0, ..., 0)^T.

Then you can use whatever algorithms, like Gauss or Gauss-Jordan elimination, to seek A = (a_1, ..., a_n)^T. If `m<n` and/or points are linear dependent, you will have free variables in `A`, otherwise `A` is unique determined. From the determined `A`, you can tell if it's possible that all the elements of `A` are integers.

Comment: Please explain why C is either the vector of ones of the null-vector. Why does C cannot be larger? (I see that we can rule out negative numbers easily of course)

Comment: @stefan `c` can be any constant, if `c` is nonzero, you can always multiply `1/c` on both sides of `a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + ... = c` to get the 'standard' form.

Comment: because the coefficients are not neccesarily divisible by c.

Comment: @stefan consider this one: `3*x_1+4*x_2=5`. Both sides multiplying 1/5 gives `3/5*x_1+4/5*x_2=1`, i.e. you will get `A=(3/5,4/5)` using the 'standard' form, then you can tell if the elements of `A` could be integers since `A` and `a*A` are essential the same for nonzero `a`

Comment: Quoting from the question " The coefficients a_i [...] must be 32-bit integers as well.". So your example has no reduced form with rhs 1 or 0.